# Convert string $ amount efficiently to integer

Tags: python, string, integer

**Set-up**

Very simple question.

I have some string $ amounts, e.g. `'$3,534.00'`, `'$6,150.00'`,`'$6,234.00'`.

I need them convert them into integers, that is, I need the following result,

`3534`,`6150`, `6234`.

---

**Code**

At the moment, I have the following seemingly inefficient code,

```
    price = '$3,534.00'
    int(price.replace('$','').replace(',','').split('.')[0])
```

which yields `3534`.

Surely there's a more elegant way?

Comment: If hundredths of a dollar (cents) is the currency granularity, then it should convert an integer representing cents, not dollars.

Comment: Parsing a currency string is a domain-specific problem, so you shouldn't expect an elegant solution in the language itself. This is a problem for libraries to solve, and there is no currency library in the standard library.

Comment: Other than creating a currency_to_int conversion function, what does *elegant* look like to you?

Comment: You could use `str.translate` for a minor speed improvement, but unless this is something that your program does hundreds of times a second, I wouldn't worry about it.  These string operations are going to be plenty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I can think of (not quite sure about its elegancy) is

```
int(float(price.strip('$').replace(',', '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it clean; i think; make a function for your work:-

```
>>> def parsefloat(var):
...     list_int = list('1234567890.')
...     v  =  str(0)
...     for i in var:
...         if i in list_int: v = v+str(i)
...     return float(v)
... 
>>> parsefloat("$%@53409uuc08n34y58.00cae")
53409083458.0
```